# PhoneGap Build: AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, phonegap-build

I've been trying to make a little test app that makes an AJAX call. When I run it using the PhoneGap Desktop server and Android developer app. everything works fine. But when I use PhoneGap Build to compile the app, install the .apk on my phone. the AJAX call fails.

I've read all over to try to find a solution to my problem. seems there are a lot of people having this issue as well, but so far I haven't been able to fix it. The most common thing I see people saying is that it's a whitelist issue. But my config.xml file contains...

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1"/>
```

as well as...

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
```

And my CSP looks like this...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Which according to  [Cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) should allow AJAX.

My app is very simple. It has a button which calls my AJAX function and passes it some info to send to the server, and a callback function...

```
<button onclick="serv('init',ajaxer)">BUTTON</button>
```

Here is my js file:

```
function ajaxer(resp){
    var e = document.getElementById("test");
    e.innerHTML="responded...";

    if(resp.go){
        e.innerHTML="IT WORKED!";
    }else{
        e.innerHTML="foo";
    }
}

function serv(request,returnFunc,parameters) { //SEND AND RECEIVE ALL SERVER INFO
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="sending info...";    

    var query="";
    var serverObject;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        serverObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        serverObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    serverObject.goto = returnFunc;

    serverObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(serverObject.readyState==4&&serverObject.status==200){
            var serverResponse = JSON.parse(serverObject.responseText);
            serverObject.goto(serverResponse);
        }
    };

    if(parameters){
        query="&"+parameters;
    }

    serverObject.open("POST", "http://tylermackenzie.duckdns.org/phoneGap%20Test/server.php", true);
    serverObject.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    serverObject.send('qType='+request+query);
}
```

When I press the button, it displays the text "sending info..." but never switches it to "responded..." or "IT WORKED!" or "foo". which means that ajaxer() was never called.

I can't understand why it's not working. Like I mentioned earlier. it works great when I use the phoneGap developer app. And I've got my phone wifi turned off while I test it. So I know that the phone is on a different network then the server because the phone has to use the mobile network. If this is just a whitelist issue, shouldn't it have the same problem when I test it with the developer app?

Also, I know it's not a problem with my server because it responds fine when I test on developer app, and when I navigate there manually.

Hoping someone can help me out.

**ADDITION**

could it have something to do with my file structure that I'm uploading to PhoneGap Build? I just used the "hello world" basic app that the PhoneGap Desktop App creates. And edited the html and js to create a little test app.

It's a little confusing to me because there is an index.html under AppName/www as well as AppName/platforms/browser and under AppName/platforms/browser/www Why are all the files tripled? I tried making all three copies be the same thing. doesn't seem to make any difference.

I read somewhere that I only need to upload the AppName/www folder to PhoneGap Build, and it seems to work just as good as uploading everything else.

Comment: @Homen whitelist is 1.2.2 and android is 6.0

Comment: @Homen ah, sorry. It says "command not found" I'm assuming because I never installed the CLI right? I don't really need it if I'm using PhoneGap Build do I?

Comment: We are having a similar problem recently.

If we "sign" the APK it is no longer getting network access.

If we do not sign the APK, and everything else is the same, the application works.

The same application also works (network connectivity) signed and unsigned on IOS.

Try building your application on phonegap build WITHOUT signing it to get over this hurdle.

I'm still trying to figure out the root cause.

Comment: @DaShaun When you say "signed" you mean creating a key for the build right? I never did create a key for the build so it seems like it's a slightly different problem

Comment: Figured out my problem!  When the package is "signed" (with a key) its a "release" build and not a "debug" build.  The release build enforces the https/ssl certificates, we had a certificate chaining issue.  So the calls were not even showing up in our logs, but it wasn't because they weren't made, it was because the android/signed.apk refused to connect to the bad certificate chain.

Comment: Also try adding an "allow-navigation" line in config.xml:

Comment: <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />

Comment: <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use jQuery to make ajax requests it is more manageable and maintainable also it is more easy to make ajax request via jQuery

also you can  debug phonegap application and see how ajax request goes and return to server and from server by using weinre remote debugger
you can follow steps presented in the following tutorial t make this
[Weinre Remote Debugging Tutorial](https://www.broken-links.com/2013/06/28/remote-debugging-with-weinre/)

I hope my answer would be useful

Comment: Just tried switching the app over to using jQuery. Again. the jQuery ajax call works great when I test it on my system using the phonegap developer app. But when I use phonegap Build. my compiled app's ajax calls fail.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't Weinre for debugging my web app before it's compiled? while it's still being developed in a browser? and not as an installed APK file. If that's true then it wouldn't do me much good because my app works great pre-compiled. it's only after I install the APK file it stops working.

Comment: the phonegap app is a webview you can still debug it using weinre, weinre is just remote debugger you can inject weinre script file the reference to your pc in application and when app opened weinre server show device connected you can then inspect ajax request and html as you do on chrome but the target is your application, I have tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a connect-src section to your Content Security Policy?  For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src *">
```

This controls where Ajax requests can be made to, see documentation at [content-security-policy.com](http://content-security-policy.com/)

Comment: Yup, had tried it before, and gave it another shot copying your bit of code. still nothing.